# How to swap an image with another when hovering on the other image?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have 5 small images and 1 image that is twice the size as the small ones. What I'm trying to do is whenever you hover on the small images the big image changes to the image you are hovering. I am having a hard time searching for methods and functions but luck as of yet. this is what I have

```
<div class="bigImg">
    <img id="image0" src="images/image1.png">
</div>
<img id="image1" src="images/image1.png">
<img id="image2" src="images/image2.png">
<img id="image3" src="images/image3.png">
<img id="image4" src="images/image4.png">
<img id="image5" src="images/image5.png">
```

I was trying to add this function that I saw somewhere else here

```
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("image0").innerHTML = '<"image2.png"/>';
}


function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("image0").innerHTML = '<img src="image1.png" />';
}
```

I wrote the img tag as

`<img id="image1" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" src="images/image1.png">`

for all of the images but wasn't working. Can someone steer me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Please define "wasn't working". What happened instead of the expected results? Errors in the console? Btw. `img` has not `innerHTML`, you've to set `src` to change the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("image0").src = 'http://lorempixel.com/g/600/600/';
}

function changePic(elem) {
    document.getElementById("image0").src = elem.src;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xn6yudLo/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Jquery you can try this.

```
<div class="bigImg"></div>
<img class="imgLink" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff" target="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff">
<img class="imgLink" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"  target="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
<img class="imgLink" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/999/fff"  target="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/999/fff">
```

**JS**

```
$('.imgLink').hover(function(){
    $('.bigImg').css({'background':'url('+ $(this).attr('target') +')'});
},function(){
    $('.bigImg').css({'background':''});
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/J8FJq/59/)

Comment: It should be noted that this solution requires the use of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Basic concept behind this is we have to catch mouseover and mouseout events. Now, on mouse over we have to change the src attribute of that particular Image and vice versa for getting back the original image.

Try this one :

```js
function mouseOver(element) {
document.getElementById(element).src = 'https://www.google.co.in/images/google_favicon_128.png';
}

function mouseOut(element) {
document.getElementById(element).src = 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png';
}
```

```html
<div class="bigImg"><img id="image0" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png"></div>
<img id="image1" onmouseover="mouseOver('image1')" onmouseout="mouseOut('image1')" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png">
<img id="image2" onmouseover="mouseOver('image2')" onmouseout="mouseOut('image2')" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png">
<img id="image3" onmouseover="mouseOver('image3')" onmouseout="mouseOut('image3')" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png">
<img id="image4" onmouseover="mouseOver('image4')" onmouseout="mouseOut('image4')" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png">
<img id="image5" onmouseover="mouseOver('image5')" onmouseout="mouseOut('image5')" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png">
```